# Drupal 7: Cannot Create Panels Page

Tags: panels, 7

I'm using Drupal 7.34 (will be updating soon) and the latest version of Panels for 7x.

When I use the Panels Dashboard (admin/structure/panels) and click Panel Page to create a new panel page, I am redirected to the Structure section immediately.

Most of the other options do the same thing, specifically: Custom Content, Custom Ruleset, and Custom Style.

Here are the modules I'm running: Panels 3.5, CTools Suite 1.7, Views 3.11, Advanced Help 1.2, Open Graph 1.3, Page Title 2.7, Global Redirect 1.5 and XML Sitemap 2.2.

I have cleared caches, and have checked permissions to ensure they are enabled, and I haven't seen this issue come up in the Known Issues. Every required module appears to be activated, though I have not activated Panels Translation.

I'm more or less a Drupal novice, so please, if you have time to help, I would be incredibly grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: This shouldn't happen. off all those modules I suspect that it might be global redirect. Try disabling it and see what happens.

Comment: I disabled Global Redirect, cleared cash, and attempted to create a panel page again. Unfortunately, the same thing is still happening. Thanks for the advice, though!

Comment: when you hover over the add page link do you see admin/structure/pages/add ?

Comment: You could try doing it on a fresh install drupal, then enable the modules you listed one by one and see any of them affects it. If it doesn't then we can conclude that it's something else.

Comment: When I hover over the link, I do see admin/structure/page/add. And I think you are probably right - I need to update anyway. Maybe that will solve the issue.

Comment: Okay, so after manually removing Panels and re-installing it, the issue vanished. I just thought I'd post this information in case it helps someone else.